# problem with using dirname(__FILE__ ,2) in php

Tags: php

I try to use dirname(**FILE** ,2)

I have index.php file in "public" directory

```
Project

  |--app

   --config

      |--init.php

   --public

      |--css
       
       --js
   
       --index.php

   --resources

      |--inc

       --langs

   --favicon.ico
```

in **index.php**

```
<?php
   $pageTitle = "Home";
   define('__BASEDIR__', dirname(__FILE__ ,2) );
   echo __BASEDIR__ . '<br>';
   require_once (__BASEDIR__ . '/config/init.php');
   ?>
```

this print: `...\xampp\htdocs\project`

in **init.php:**

```
<?php

     $templ  = __BASEDIR__ . '/resources/inc/';

     $lang   = __BASEDIR__ . '/resources/langs/';

     $css    = __BASEDIR__ . '/public/css/';

     $js     = __BASEDIR__ . '/public/js/';

      echo $templ .'<br>';

      echo $lang .'<br>';

      echo $css .'<br>';

      echo $js .'<br>';

      require_once $templ . 'header.php';

      require_once $templ . 'navbar.php';
```

it shows in the browser

```
...\xampp\htdocs\project

...\xampp\htdocs\project/resources/inc/

...\xampp\htdocs\project/resources/langs/

...\xampp\htdocs\project/public/css/

...\xampp\htdocs\project/public/js/
```

**Note this** `...\project/....            /*  backslash */`

The browser cannot find files (style.css, script.js....)

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**
if the difference in slashes bothers you, you can set your path's using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` like so

From

```
$templ  = __BASEDIR__ . '/resources/inc/';
```

to

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$templ  = __BASEDIR__.DS.'resources'.DS.'inc'.DS;
```

**Secondly** You will not be able to use that relative pathing to load browser resources like js and css files. You need to look into absolute path.

**Example**: Say your on windows, the path `$templ` will be something along those lines `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\css\file.css` which will not work for loading your browser resources. If your document root is `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\` you will need to use `/public/css/file.css` to load your css or js files.

Comment: I have put in a init.php file : $css    = '/public/css/';                                                             and in header.php file : <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css . 'style.css'; ?>">     so appear in browser (view source) <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">     Should I just do this without having to write define('__BASEDIR__', dirname(__FILE__ ,2) ); ??

Comment: You can still use your `__BASEDIR__` var to load resources in your PHP code. But if the purpose of all your `__BASEDIR__` links is only to load them in the front-end through HTML then yes you can get rid of it.

Comment: @nacira2019 You are very welcome. _(temp comment to be removed)_